# modifying webSocket method to return actor ref

Tags: java, scala, playframework, websocket, akka

i have a function like this

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>

    homelogger.info(logMessages.connectionEstablished)

    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => SocketHandlerClass.props(out,postActor))

    /* out is an actor-ref for a particular connection to send messages back */


  }
```

I am working in Play 2.5.3 and Akka 2.4.7.
How the above method is modified to return actor reference i.e. out?

Comment: Don't  ask same question with different titles

Comment: read the question too. How can you figure out this as a duplicate of that one. are the solution same? think.

Answer (score 0):

`ActorFlow` is Provides a flow that is handled by an actor. It still gives u `actorref` for browser connected instance. 
you can use below example to get actor ref , its better way. Though   `actorflowmaterlizer` is implicit  used in play framework.

> Don't need to use `ActorFlow` get `actorref`

```
 def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>out=>  SocketHandlerClass.props(out,postActor)
// no need to return out
      }
```

Comment: not clear. Please clear your approach.

Comment: @AniketPandey u can use above code to return 'out' as  actorref

Comment: u mean ` def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>out=>
      SocketHandlerClass.props(out,postActor)
  (out)   }`

Comment: @AniketPandey yes, but why do u want to return out?

Comment: well it doesn't work

Comment: @AniketPandey check out now i updated answer

Comment: then how will i get the reference out? i want it so that i can use that connection instance for different purpose.

Comment: If u want to use out , create a hashmap under SocketHandlerClass like, val connection =new Hashmap[String,ActorRef] and using SocketHandlerClass.connection.push("<uid>"-> out)